# Need help with identifying distribution by PDF

Tags: distributions, density-function, skewness

This sort of question has been asked countless times on stats, but I could not find an answer specific to my case. I have an empirical distribution whose PDF is in the picture below. The distribution is "normal"-like but, in general, asymmetric both in the central part and in the tails (the left tail is "lean", the right tail is "fat"). Are there any theoretical distributions that I could use to fit my data, and if so, what are their names and closed-form representations?

In other words, I would like to control the position, width, skewness, and the "fatness" of each tail.

[image: CDF]

Comment: What are you hoping for apart from "yes"?  The graph is too indefinite to go beyond that.

Comment: Hoping for the name of a theoretical distribution (and its closed-form representation).

Comment: This is not a CDF

Comment: @gunes Sorry, a slip of my tongue. Fixed.

Comment: Any number of densities might be a reasonable *approximation*. Why do you need an explicit density function approximation? (Note also that there's a fairly close connection between skewness and the fatness of the two tails)

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Indeed, I want any reasonable approximation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, based on the flexibility of the distribution (in shape) and breath in applications, the two-parameter Weibull distribution.

[Here is a source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution). [EDIT] Moreover, the source notes that the skewness and coefficient of variation depend only on the shape parameter.

A further generalization of the Weibull distribution is the Hyperbolastic distribution of Type III, see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolastic_functions .

Comment: To respond to the question you will need to propose a family of distributions with at least *four* parameters ("position, width, skewness, and the fatness").  Even then, the question is vague.

Comment: Thanks, I added the Hyperbolastic distribution.

Comment: That appears to be a growth model, not a family of distributions. Although some of those functions can serve as PDFs, they look like they are limited to three parameters (and those parameters are not easily related to the four parameters of the question).